# Injecting dependency angularMoment returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to access moment.js API, injecting `angularMoment` as a dependency into my module but it's returning error:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=momentProvider%20%3C-%20moment%20%3C-%20transCtrl`

I'm following the docs provided by https://github.com/urish/angular-moment but an error keeps being returned. Any idea why?

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment']);

app.controller('transCtrl', ['moment', function(moment){

    $scope.date = new moment();  

}]);
```

Comment: You need to include `moment.js` too (Before `angular-moment.min.js`)

Comment: Ahhh, I had originally, not sure what happened there. Have done but still same error appears :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detail on how to use angular-moment

```
https://github.com/urish/angular-moment
```

You have to include both moment.js and angular-moment.js in your application.

Comment: Just added the file, placed it before `angular-moment.js` and there is still the error?

Comment: try this 
app.controller('transCtrl', ['$scope', 'moment', function ($scope, moment) {
       $scope.date = new moment();  
    }]);

If it still gives you an error, create a fiddle and attach the link here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, after you included the `moment.js` script before `angular-moment.min.js` as I suggested in the comments to your question - You now have a simple error in your controller:

```
app.controller('transCtrl', ['$scope', 'moment', function($scope, moment){
```

You just need to inject `$scope` into your controller.